# How to only index collection items that match specific condition?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my project I want to index the data.

The code of views:

```
- @phones.each.with_index(1) do |(phone,no_of_duplicate),index|
  .row.py-2
     .col-2 = index
    - if no_of_duplicate.count > 1      
     .col-3 = phone
     .col-3 = no_of_duplicate.count
     .col-4 .......................................
```

I obtain the result as
[image: output obtain as]
If I change the code on views as:

```
- @phones.each.with_index(1) do |(phone,no_of_duplicate),index|
 - if no_of_duplicate.count > 1
  .row.py-2
    .col-2 = index
    .col-3 = phone
    .col-3 = no_of_duplicate.count
```

The got the result as:
[image: Output obtain as]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can `filter` before assigning indexes and rendering:

```
@phones.filter { |(_,no_of_duplicate)| no_of_duplicate.count > 1 }.each <...>
```